# "Fri, 12 Sep 2014 05:00:23 GMT"，what's wrong with SimpleDateFormat？

Tags: android, datetime, time, timezone, simpledateformat

"Fri, 12 Sep 2014 05:00:23 GMT"，what's wrong with SimpleDateFormat？

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
sdf.parse(dateString);
format：    "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'"
dateString："Fri, 12 Sep 2014 05:00:23 GMT"
```

what's wrong ?

Comment: What's the error / expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: report the error:java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri, 12 Sep 2014 05:00:23 GMT"

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your problem is that the date is coming out wrong, the `SimpleDateFormat` conversion specifier for timezone is `z` rather than `'GMT'` (although you can use `Z` and `X` for the other two variants, RFC822 and ISO8601 respectively).

With your specifier, I get a *local* time of 5am. If I use the correct specifier in my code, it works fine:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String format = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z";
        String date = "Fri, 12 Sep 2014 05:00:23 GMT";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        try {
            Date dt = sdf.parse(date);
            System.out.println(dt);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of that program (for Perth, Western Australia, which is UTC+8) is, as expected:

```
Fri Sep 12 13:00:23 WST 2014
```

See the [`SimpleDateFormat` online documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more detail.

If you still have troubles, try removing the individual items from your format and date strings until it starts working. Once you've established the problematic format specifier, it will be easier to track down.

Comment: why still wrong in my program? It report :java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri, 12 Sep 2014 05:00:23 GMT"

Comment: Then you _may_ have something like a locale issue. I'm assuming you've changed it to use the right specifier, yes? I'll update the answer with some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Use "z" in your pattern because GMT is not just a literal but has to be interpreted as timezone offset UTC+00:00. And set the locale to English because you have english abbreviations of day-of-week and month:

```
String format = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z";
String date = "Fri, 12 Sep 2014 05:00:23 GMT";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH);
```